# Методы в потоках Net

Tags: c#, .net, многопоточность, функции

Выполнится ли метод в том же потоке где была вызвана?

Например: Я создаю поток для метода `threadm`.
Затем, из этого метода я вызываю другой метод `Something()`.

И вот мой вопрос, будет ли выполняться `Something` в потоке `threadm`

```
        public void threadm()
        {
            //Что то выполняем
            while(true)
            {
            //Что то выполняем
            }
            Something();
        }
        public void Something()
        {
            //Что то выполняем


        }
```

Comment: если кратко, то да

Comment: Всё будет в одном потоке. Это легко проверить. Поставь точку останова в методе Something и посмотри Thread.Current.